# Would you add an owner_id in the parent table or a is_owner in the child table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Let's say you have a table

```
collection
    id
    name
```

and a table

```
collection_collaborator
    id
    user_id
```

Would you add an owner_id in parent table?

```
collection
    id
    name
    owner_id
```

Would you add a is_owner on child table??

```
collection_collaborator
    id
    name
    is_owner
```

Comment: Could you please expand more on the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: First determine whether you are talking about a "one-to-many" (and in which direction) or a "many-to-many" relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no black and white answer to this question - really depends on your business requirements and your own preferences.

There is one distinct difference between the two approaches: `owner_id` field indicates that the collection can have a single owner only, while the `is_owner` flag allows for multiple owners for a single collection.

The other deciding factor could be the reports on the data. If you have `owner_id` field, then you can display the owner information for a collection without needing to join on the collaborator table. If you have lots of reports where you need the owner information, but do not need any other information around the collaborators, then `owner_id` field can increase the performance of your queries.

Comment: I think this part "owner_id field indicates that the collection can have a single owner only, while the is_owner flag allows for multiple owners for a single collection." is the one that makes sense to me. The collection will only have one owner, so I think I will take that approach (owner_id)